# How to replace first word with last word?

Tags: python

```
def changeWord(s):
    firstWord = s.split()[0]
    lastWord = s.split()[-1]
```

I've managed to get the last and first word myself but have been stuck at replacing the first word with the last word while keeping the rest of the input as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to achieve this:

```
def changeWord(s):
    first, *middle, last = s.split() # Add this line to get first, middle and last word(s)
    print(last, *middle, first)
```

Input:

```
changeWord('Stackoverflow! to Welcome')
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Stackoverflow!
```

Comment: Solutions like this are why I love Python